# Android For Work | Automatic installation of apps

Tags: android

I'm working on Device Policies with Android for Work and have almost finished the task but for one thing - how do I make a white-listed app automatically installed?

In the white-list of apps for the Work Profile, I can see the app I've added. I'd like to make its installation automatic (or would like to know if that's possible in the first place). Here's the screen-shot:

[image: The app installation is set as 'Manual']

The row is clickable, which, I hoped, would lead me to a screen with options. The URL implies so, but all I see is a blank screen.

[image]

Sorcery?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should see a screen with "Preferences section" with 3 checkbox to set as you want :

- Auto-install
- Prevent users from uninstalling the app
- Allow users to add widgets on the home screen

(labels might be different, I use GApps in French and I'm translating it for you right down)

And of course, you have to check the first one.

If you don't see it, it may be simply because of rights administration, even if I'm doubting, because you managed to add apps to white-list, so...

Are you allowed to make this kind of setting ? You should check what are your rights exactly. If you're not the super administrator, you should be at least Android for work Administrator. Check also if your rights are for the whole domain, or just some specific "organizations".

These settings may be changed in the users section in the Google Apps Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It has been some time since I faced the problem. The task has been on the backburner since. Nonetheless, what you're saying might exactly be the problem. I will revisit this in time and acknowledge this answer accordingly.